# In R, image processing loop takes an order of magnitude longer to process after ~50 iterations

Tags: r, imagemagick

EDIT: changed the image names from Image1-Image11 to Image50-Image60 for clarity.

EDIT2: Solved by adding a garbage collection command after removing the image file in each loop iteration. Code is updated.

I have 400+ jpeg images in a folder. I'm trying write a script to: read each image, identify some text in the image, and then write the file name and that text into a data frame.

When I run the script below, the first ~50 iterations print a time of .1-.3 seconds. Then, for a few iterations, the iteration will take 1-3 seconds. Then, this bumps up to 1-5 minutes, after which I kill the script.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magick)

fileList3 = list.files(path = filePath)

printJobXRes = data.frame(
                          jobName = as.character(),
                          xRes = as.numeric(),
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE
                          )
i = 0

for (fileName in fileList3){
  img = paste0(filePath, '/', fileName, '_TestImage.jpg')
  start_time = Sys.time()
  temp.xRes = image_read(img, strip = T) %>% 
    image_rotate(270) %>% 
    image_crop('90x150+1750') %>% 
    image_negate %>%
    image_convert(type = 'Bilevel') %>%
    image_ocr %>%
    as.numeric

  stop_time = Sys.time()
  i = i+1
  print(paste(fileName,'first attempt, item #', i))
  print(stop_time-start_time)

  temp.df3 = data.frame(
    jobName = fileName,
    xRes = temp.xRes,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  printJobXRes = rbind(printJobXRes, temp.df3)
  rm(temp.xRes)
  rm(temp.df3)
  rm(img)
  gc() #This solved the issue
}
```

Here's a couple lines of the output:

```
#Images 1-49 process in .1-.3 seconds each
[1] "Image50.jpg first attempt, item # 50"
Time difference of 0.2320111 secs
[1] "Image51.jpg first attempt, item # 51"
Time difference of 0.213742 secs
[1] "Image52.jpg first attempt, item # 52"
Time difference of 0.2536581 secs
[1] "Image53.jpg first attempt, item # 53"
Time difference of 1.253844 secs
[1] "Image54.jpg first attempt, item # 54"
Time difference of 1.149764 secs
[1] "Image55.jpg first attempt, item # 55"
Time difference of 1.171134 secs
[1] "Image56.jpg first attempt, item # 56"
Time difference of 1.397093 secs
[1] "Image57.jpg first attempt, item # 57"
Time difference of 1.201915 secs
[1] "Image58.jpg first attempt, item # 58"
Time difference of 1.455768 secs
[1] "Image59.jpg first attempt, item # 59"
Time difference of 1.618744 secs
[1] "Image60.jpg first attempt, item # 60" 
Time difference of 4.527751 mins
```

Can anyone offer suggestions as to why the loop doesn't continue to take ~.1-.3 seconds? All jpgs are roughly the same size, resolution, and all generated from the same source.

Comment: Welcome Nick, please provide MWE. I can not replicate your issue. Is "Image11" always the problem? The one thing you could try is instead of continually `rbind`ing you could pass into a list and then used `do.call(rbind, yourlist)` after your loop

Comment: Hi George, unfortunately I'm unable to share the images for privacy reasons. "Image11" isn't always the problem. The jumps in time it takes to process the image change each time the code is ran.

Comment: Can you predefine the size / number of rows of your dataframe? Letting a dataframe grow makes it very slow if it becomes big.

Comment: I certainly could, but right now it's maxing at ~450 rows which I don't think is too large. Plus, the start and stop times are measured right before and after the image processing, meaning only that step should be contributing to the times that are printed out.

Comment: Have you tried watching the amount of memory the process uses as time goes on? Processes often slow down because memory usage is growing and space becomes tight.

Comment: I added a garbage collection to the loop, that solved the issue. Thanks for the suggestion @MarkSetchell!

Comment: Cool, glad it helped. Feel free to write it up yourself and bag the points!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my issue based on Mark's suggestion. I was removing the image file from memory in each loop iteration, but the freed up memory was never realized by R. I added a garbage collection command (gc()) into the loop to fix this issue, and the loop then ran as expected.